# Values of coefficients of polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Suppose we have the polynomial on $\mathbb{C}$:

$$p(z)=a_nz^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \dots + a_1z+a_0$$

and the factored form:

$$p(z)=a_n(z-z_1)^{d_1}(z-z_2)^{d_2} \dots (z-z_r)^{d_r}, \sum_{i=1}^r{d_i} =deg(p(z))$$

Show that $a_{n-1}=-a_n(d_1z_1+d_2z_2+\dots+d_rz_r)$.

I've taken a few stabs at substituting between the factored form and the usual form, but I can't seem to get this result.

Comment: Suppose you were to take the derivative $ \ \frac{dp}{dz} \ ... $

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this helps me. It seems to have made things even more complex!

Comment: OK, we don't have to go that route.  The factored form is just there to tell you the multiplicities of the roots $ \ z_k \ . $  So $ \ z_1 \ $ has multiplicity $ \ d_1 \ , $ and so forth.  For the basic expression of the polynomial, what is the relationship between $ \ a_n \ $ and $ \ a_{n-1} \ $ that tells us something about the roots of the polynomial? [Hint: Viete's formulas]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two expressions for the polynomial $p$, namely :

$$p(z)=\color{darkblue}{a_{n}z^{n}}+\color{magenta}{a_{n-1}z^{n-1}}+\ldots +a_{1}z+a_{0} \tag{$\star$}$$

and

$$p(z) = a_{n}(z-z_{1})^{d_{1}}(z-z_{2})^{d_{2}}\ldots(z-z_{r})^{d_{r}} \tag{$\star\star$}$$

To find the relation you want, just expand the second expression and compare with the first. $a_{n-1}$ is the coefficient of $z^{n-1}$ so, when expanding the second expression for $p(z)$, you only have to keep coefficients which are weighted by $z^{n-1}$. Note that :

$$ (z-z_{i})^{d_{i}} = \sum_{k=0}^{d_{i}} \mathrm{C}_{d_{i}}^{k} z^{k} (-z_{i})^{d_{i}-k} = z^{d_{i}} - d_{i}z_{i}z^{d_{i}-1} + \ldots$$

So, $(\star\star)$ becomes :

$$ p(z) = a_{n} \big( z^{d_{1}} - d_{1}z_{1}z^{d_{1}-1} + \ldots \big)\big( z^{d_2} -d_{2}z_{2}z^{d_{2}-1} + \ldots \big)\ldots\big(z^{d_{r}} - d_{r}z_{r}z^{d_{r}-1} + \ldots \big) $$

Now, just expand this : in each factor $\big( z^{d_{i}} - d_{i}z_{i}z^{d_{i}-1} + \ldots \big)$, take $z^{d_{i}}$, except in one, in which you will take $-d_{j}z_{j}z^{d_{j}-1}$. You should find :

$$ p(z) = a_{n}z^{d_{1}}z^{d_{2}}\ldots z^{d_{r}} + a_{n}\big(-d_{1}z_{1}z^{d_{1}-1}z^{d^{2}}\ldots z^{d_{r}} - z^{d_{1}}d_{2}z_{2}z^{d_{2}-1}z^{d_{3}}\ldots z^{d_{r}} - \ldots - z^{d_{1}}\ldots d_{r}z_{r}z^{d_{r}-1} \big) + \ldots $$

In the end,

$$ p(z) = \color{darkblue}{a_{n}z^{n}} + \color{magenta}{a_{n}\big( -d_{1}z_{1} \ldots - d_{r}z_{r} \big)z^{n-1}} + \ldots $$